# Domain-specific languages for solving algebra problems?

Tags: math, dsl, algebra

Udacity is offering a lockdown deal for nanodegrees. I'm trying to figure out which of their two pricing plans is more worthwhile depending on how long it takes to complete the course. I'll present the math problem in its entirety here, but if you'd like to skip to the software part, feel free to jump down to the bold section below.

You can pay $226/month for three months, all upfront, or pay $399/month for as long as needed starting with the second month.

Algebraically, this looks like the following, with the first deal on the left and the second on the right, with *m* representing current time in months. The floor function is used to account for the first month being free, and future months being paid by the month (i.e. 1 month and 1 day is the same price as 2 months).

[image: Udacity deal cost equation]
*P.S. Please add MathJax to Stack Overflow. Making this and the following LaTeX images was much harder than it needs to be.*

We can solve this particular example fairly trivially by multiplying out the left side, and then dividing by the *$399* on the right.

[image: Equation after multiplying out left side and dividing by $399]
[image: Equation after simplifying]

Finally, we can see that this is only true with the floored *t* when the unfloored *t* is past the floor minimum (floor floor? hehe).

[image: Final result of equation]

**So if the course takes at least two months to complete, it is worth going with the $226/month deal. Otherwise, one is best off taking the month-by-month. Now this example is small and easy, but this got me thinking about the process here, and there really should be tools that do this for you. I'm sure plenty of industries have need for mechanisms for solving these types of problems with domain-specific languages. Do such languages exist?**

Comment: Do some research into topics such as *linear programming*, *constraint satisfaction*, *computer algebra*.  You will find many many useful references and more than a handful of software systems designed for the domains in which your problem lies.  But this question is arguably off-topic here, seeking, as it does, pointers to off-site resources.

Comment: Have a look at Maxima and Axiom, or, if you have a Raspberry Pi, you can run Wolfram Mathematica for free.